# MKDirections with midpoints

Tags: ios, mapkit

Is it possible to get polyline from A to B with waypoints in the middle using Apple Maps API? I tried requesting like this:

`A -> A1` `A1 -> A2` `A2 -> A3` ... `AN -> B`

but obviously Apple servers stop responding when I do it too often, so I am looking for one way how to get it nicely without overloading Apple servers like this:

`A -> A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> .... -> B`

Anybody knows the way how to accomplish this?